# Getting error while publishing message to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, producer

I am new to Kafka. I have written a simple JAVA program to generate a message using avro schema. I have generated a specific record. The record is generated successfully. My schema is not yet registered with my local environment. It is currently registered with some other environment.

I am using the apache kafka producer library to publish the message to my local environment kafka topic. Can I publish the message to the local topic or the schema needs to be registered with the local schema registry as well.

Below are the producer properties -

````
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        properties.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "https://schema-registry.xxxx.service.dev:443");```

Error I am getting while publishing the message -
``` org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: 
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: User is denied operation Write on Subject: xxx.avro-value; error code: **40301**
````

Comment: Could you please share Avro file and request payload you used. I'm presuming Schema registry is the right one and as you mentioned running on remote system is up and running.

Comment: It seems the client does not have permissions to create a new schema and topic. Also are you using rest proxy to ineract with kafka? 40301 is a forbidden code for  Authorized clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was kafka producer by default tries to register the schema on topic. So, I added the below -         properties.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);
and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by adding the property

```
spring:
   kafka:
      producer:
            value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer
      properties:
        auto:
          register:
            schemas: false
```